# How can I disable prev button on first image? (BASIC JQUERY SLIDER)

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using basic jquery slider and I want to disable prev/next button on first/last image.

How can I do that?

LINK : http://www.wapsmag.com/archives/7996

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional statement ..Within that use **(#rightClick).unbind('click')**. Similar code for the other side.